# How to format json in javascript file in Visual studio code when formatOnSave is true?

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio-code

```
var obj = {
  name: "xyz",
  routes: {
    "": "showView1",
    "view2": "showView2",
    "view3": "showView3"
  }
}
```

If I save this code in a `.js` file in vscode automatically my json object property double quotes are removed , like below

```
var obj = {
  name: "xyz",
  routes: {
    "": "showView1",
    view2: "showView2",
    view3: "showView3"
  }
}
```

The code is perfectly working fine in `.JSON` file. What are the setting that I need to change to save my code as it is without voiding double quotes when saved?

Comment: Why? The quotes aren't required in a JS file, you already left them out of other parts of the same object!

Comment: This is coming from one of your extensions. VS Code's built-in JavaScript formatter should not touch quotes in object literals

Answer (score 0):

In my case the prettier extension was automatically removing quotes in JSON strings. Disabling it solved the issue.